# Looking for optimised algo for specific combination problem

Tags: algorithm

I just want to check if we have a generic optimized algo for this problem-

Suppose we have different baskets with fruits

1. Basket A - Apple Orange Guava
2. Basket B - Mango
3. Basket C - Guava
4. Basket D - Mango Guava
5. Basket E-  Mango Orange

Now if a user gives a fruit combination of Mango Guava for search, we should return all possible combinations mapping resulting in the input fruit combination. It is OK if there are some extra fruits not given in input. But there should not be duplicates.

1. Basket D
2. Basket B, Basket C
3. Basket A, Basket B
4. Basket E, Basket C

Item 1 is full match while 2/3/4 are partial matches.

We dont want a duplicate fruit in the resultant combination. For eg Basket B, Basket D should not be returned as Mango is common in both the basket.

One possible approach is this algo-
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combinations-from-n-arrays-picking-one-element-from-each-array/

Is there any other approach apart from brute force picking from each basket and checking if the result has all the required products.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is known as the [exact cover problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover).

Comment: Exact Cover is a special case of this problem: It's the problem you get when you restrict the target combination of fruit to always be the complete set of fruits (and you only care about finding one combination of baskets that works). So, this problem is at least as hard as Exact Cover, which is an NP-hard problem, so it's very unlikely that an algorithm exists that solves every instance quickly.